# USB hub driver on Kernel 3.4

Tags: linux, drivers, usb

I have a linux kernel version 3.45 which I can't update, I'm trying to connect a USB hub from SMSC (USB2514B), I can see that this model was supported natively in recent kernels but mine can't support it.

How can I port the driver to my kernel?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to locate the relevant driver in the earliest kernel that supported it, and graft that on your museum piece. But I'd wagger it will be a *huge* undertaking, the Linux folks feel absolutely no compunction in redoing the kernel-internal interfaces. Current kernel is 5.5.4, 3.45 is ancient (and is not one of the long term support versions either, where there could be some hope of a backport).

I'm afraid your best bet is to get supported hardware.